# What is the effect of specifying the Target of an Objective-C class in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

What is happening when I specify the project (or test) when I click this selection?

I can't seem to find a a good resource explaining *why* I have to select the targets, only that in order to use my class, I must have a target associated with the class.

Comment: tl;dr version: So you can have for example, unit tests, that's not compiled as part of your main project, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Targets basically specify the product that should be built.  Your app could have multiple targets.  I.e. a keyboard extension is a target and the main app for the keyboard extension is another target.  If you have a class that is to be used in one or the other products, you must specify its target.